# Double and Triple Intergral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This may be a silly question but I have trouble grasping this very basic concept.

In equations, sometimes we have

$$ \int_0^\pi \int_x^\pi \frac{\sin y}{y} dydx$$

function given as f(x,y). And other times it's just double or triple integral with 1 as f(x,y) followed by dydx.

What does this f(x,y) do in getting the volume of the object?
Can't we just set f(x,y) = 1 , and get volume by having correct integrals?

Comment: In double integral I guess f(x,y) gives the z-value, which can be useful in calculating volume. But why do we need f(x,y,z) in triple integral? Other than f(x,y,z) being 1?

Comment: The $f(x,y,z)$ in a triple integral may be a *density* so the integral is finding *mass* rather than volume. Or the charge density, leading to total electric charge. Volume is not the only thing found with triple integrals! For that matter, $f(x,y,z)$ could also be the $w$ component of a 4-dimensional figure, and the integral is for 4D volume.

Comment: but isn't $\delta(x,y,z)$ different from $f(x,y,z)$? If I understand correctly, f(x,y,z) in triple integral has no effect whatsoever on volume?

Comment: The only difference between $\delta(x,y,z)$ and $f(x,y,z)$ is the names. And using $f(x,y,z)$ definitely has an effect on the triple integral, but the integral may not be trying to find a 3-dimensional volume.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the volume: $V=\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \int_x^\pi \int_0^{\sin(y)/y} 1\operatorname d z\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\\ = \displaystyle\int_0^\pi \int_x^\pi \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\\ = \displaystyle\int_0^\pi \operatorname{Si}(\pi)-\operatorname{Si}(x)\operatorname d x\\=2 $